# file watcher job which is going to error with Error Code 143. Issue is sporadic in nature

Tags: autosys

We need input from someone from Autosys on file watcher job.
There is one file watcher job which is going to error with Error Code 143.
The file watcher job checks if file is present on the remote server or not.

The same job runs from fine for non production instances. However inProduction for some reason it fails sporadically with error code 143.  The error does not depend on if the file is there or not there .

Answer (score 0):

The above error code 143 states that the issue pertain to the "The system cannot join or substitute a drive to or for a directory on the same drive". you can check the same in the exit code list for further research on this..